# r remove words which begins and ends with dashes

Tags: r, regex

How to remove words with dashes (as prefixes or suffixes) from such string:

`x <- "word -o -dod -3 -33 dp-pd -d- --- 140 -- s- S- SS- s3- 3e- 33- 3- s SS avf-ada"`

And obtain:

`word dp-pd 140 s SS avf-ada`

Occasionally, standalone dashes also can be removed.

I've found a solution thanks to regex101: `(\s-\S+)|(\S+-\s)`

Comment: Nevermind. I've found a solution thanks to regex101.
`(\s-\S+)|(\S+-\s)`

Comment: What about `-o word -o`?

Comment: I see. My code doesn't match the first token. It's not very much loss in huge string, but anyway thanks for being so open-eyed.

Comment: I posted a solution for this. See below.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
x <- "word -o -dod -3 -33 dp-pd -d- --- 140 -- s- S- SS- s3- 3e- 33- 3- s SS avf-ada -"
trimws(gsub("(?:\\S+-\\B|\\B-\\S+|\\B-\\B)\\s*", "", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSX0y7/2) and an [R demo](http://ideone.com/zwykfB).

**Details**:

- `(?:\S+-\B|\B-\S+|\B-\B)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\S+-\B` - 1+ chars other than whitespace, `-` and a non-word boundary, that is, the `-` must be either at the end of string or before a non-word char
  - `|` - or
  - `\B-\S+` - a non-word boundary, that is, the `-` should only be matched if preceded with a non-word char or start of string, then a hyphen and 1+ chars other than whitespace
  - `\B-\B` - any `-` enclosed with non-word boundaries (at the end/start of string or between non-word chars)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

The `perl=TRUE` needs to be used because of the non-word boundary that does not work correctly with a TRE regex version.

Comment: Thanks. However, ideone.com works perfectly, but on regex101 it doesn't match single dashes. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: No idea what you mean by single dashes, your regex does not match single dashes either.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for little mess. I've add one segment to the pattern: `(?:\S+-\B|\B-\S+|\B-\B)` so it's now what I wanted.

Comment: I see, I updated the answer and added an explanation.